# Meteor Account Login with facebook not working on the server

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

So here's my simple code

```
Meteor.loginWithFacebook({
  requestPermissions: ['user_friends', 'public_profile', 'email'],
}, (err) => {
  console.log('Received response');
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error logging in with facebook ' + err);

    // onAuthenticationFail();
  } else {
    // onAuthenticationPass();
    console.log('Authentication Successful');
  }
});
```

All it is doing right now is `console.log()` for each possible condition. It works fine in localhost. On the server though, the facebook dialog pops up, give permission and the dialog disappears. This is expected but it looks like the callback is never called.

Neither is the `Accounts.onCreateUser()` invoked.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was not really about meteor. Maybe a little. So the mongodb installed on my server was 2.4 where meteor 1.3 requires 2.6. I updated my mongodb and everything started working as expected